# How can I create new react app using create-react-app` but without expo?

Tags: react-native, create-react-app

I need to initialize a new react native project. Recommended method to create a react native project is by using a tool called `create-react-app`.

But this tool comes with built in 'expo' tool-chain which omit creating `./android` directory within my application root directory.

Is there a way to tell while `create-react-app` command to create the app without integrating "Expo" ?

Why I need this is that i want to use some external native Java libraries integrated with my react-native app.

Comment: check [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#installing-dependencies)

Comment: @RaviRupareliya which says i have to use `react-native init` instead of `create-react-app` right?

Comment: Yes, absolutely right, you can use `react-native-cli` for `react-native init` command

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the new archictecure with Hermes (RN version 0.70 or later), you can run:

```bash
npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject
```

Where the name of your project can replace `AwesomeProject`.

As they note, first make sure to remove `react-native-cli` if you have it installed globally.

```bash
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli @react-native-community/cli
```

Read more from the [official docs here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/the-new-architecture/use-app-template).